# Wireless tagging for beginners

Tags: wireless, modeling, tag

I will preface this question with a caveat: I'm a reasonably talented programmer, but an absolute novice in electronics. This will be my first project.

My dad has a 1/19th scale model railway. I'd quite like to add announcements to the passenger trains, of the form "This station is X. Welcome aboard the HH:MM service to Y."

I thought it might be possiblw to swipe a "destination" tag at the beginning of the journey to set Y. X would be set by a tag at the station when the train passes/rests for a couple of seconds. The range, i guess, would be about 80mm from the building to the far edge of the track. It'd be worth bearing in mind that, being on a train, exact positioning will be a challenge and so *either* it'd need to be read just as the train passed the station *or* have a longer range to allow for stopping in the wrong place.

Does that sound (a) feasible, (b) the best way to do it, and (c) relatively easy?

Ideally the components would be fairly low cost. Adding some level of electrical power to the station buildings would be possible (they'd basically be balsa wood boxes).

Longer term, I'd be thinking about possibly adding other things on to this system (e.g. automatic points switching), but wanted to bring it down to a minimal system/infrastructure before attempting anything fancy.

Comment: It's a case of try it and see, then hone the design.

Answer (score 0):

80mm is possible with most cheap off-the shelf readers that have using an 80mm square antenna.

I'd be looking to get closer to the tag. eg put the antenna under the track or between the rails or inside one of those communications junction boxes.